# Build a query to join multiple rows for same user on a single row (Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access-2010

Apologies if this has already been answered, I searched and searched but could not find this exact scenario.

I have a table of users, and a table with activities (add or remove). I would like to combine these into a single result via a query, with AddDate and RemoveDate as columns in the query.

Here is a sample of my data, and what I'm looking for.

```
Users
==============
ID  User
--------------
1   John Doe
2   Jane Doe
3   John Smith

Activities
===========================================
ID  UserID  ActivityType    ActivityDate
-------------------------------------------
1   1       Add             1/1/2017
2   2       Add             1/3/2017
3   3       Add             2/2/2017
4   1       Remove          2/6/2017
```

This is what I'd like my query to return

```
User           AddDate     RemoveDate
=====================================
John Doe       1/1/2017    2/6/2017
Jane Doe       1/3/2017
John Smith     2/2/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it again fresh this morning, I figured it out. Posting the answer for when I inevitably forget a year from now and have to Google for an answer!

```
SELECT [User], 
       [AddDate],
       [RemoveDate]
FROM (( [Users]
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT [UserID],
                   [ActivityDate] AS AddDate
            FROM   [Activities]
            WHERE  [ActivityType] = "Add" ) AS [A1]
                   ON [Users].[ID] = [A1].[UserID])
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT [UserID],
                   [ActivityDate] AS RemoveDate
            FROM   [Activities]
            WHERE  [ActivityType] = "Remove" ) AS [A2]
                   ON [Users].[ID] = [A2].[UserID])
```